# Ruby on rails , test is saying a column doesn't exist but its on the schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my clients table, I have a column named email. But when I made the tests for the clients controller and the model, the tests kept on saying that the clients table has no column named email.

SQLite3::SQLException: table clients has no column named email: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_clients_on_email" ON "clients" ("email")

although I do admit that I didn't initially put that column when I created my table, but I added the column via a separate migration. I ran rake db:migrate and even tried rake db:drop:all, rake db:create:all and then rake db:migrate and it still didn't change anything.

the email column was also added as an index for the clients table.

this is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161230163248) do

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.text     "email",      null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "clients", ["email"], name: "index_clients_on_email", unique: true

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "project_description", null: false
    t.string   "project_timescale"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.integer  "client_id"
  end

  add_index "projects", ["client_id"], name: "index_projects_on_client_id"

end
```

the initial migration for the clients table:

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :name, presence: true, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

migration to add email as an index for the client table:

```
class AddIndexToClient < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index:clients, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

migration to add the email column:

```
class AddEmailToClient < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :clients, :email, :text
  end
end
```

the following is my database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Do you use same database for dev and test environment? Try 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate' and please show your database.yml

Comment: I never really paid attention to that detail and I don't remember having consciously switching between the two environments. Where can I find my database.yml?

Comment: never mind, I just found it.

Comment: it's in config folder. what test framework do you use? can you show your test?

Comment: try to run 'rake db:test:prepare'

Comment: that command is not working, should i try rake db:rollback? the only problem is that I wont be able to use rake db:migrate because the error is stopping me from migrating.

Comment: what is your Rails version? can you try `bin/rake`? Maybe you need to recreate test database with `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate:reset`

Comment: I am using Rails version 4.2.6. Sorry for the late reply by the way I wasn't able to respond earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: I just tried it, and afterwards I tried rake db:migrate and it brought up the same error.

Comment: This fixed for me. Bizarre that the helper from the command line insists to run `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` instead of `rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test`